# How can I create a dblink from Postgresql 8.3 to SQL Server (2000 and 2008)?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linux, database-link, postgresql-8.3

I have a Postgresql database that need to read data from two SQL Servers (one SQL Server 2000 and one SQL Server 2008).

I want to setup two dblinks to the SQL Servers.

After googling, foruming, reading documentation, I struggle to find something production ready.

What tool can I use ?

Comment: Have you seen this article? http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/249-ODBC-Foreign-Data-wrapper-to-query-SQL-Server-on-Window---Part-2.html

Comment: Check out DBI-Link.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should be aware that PostgreSQL 8.3 will [soon be going EOL](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).  You should probably use a more current version.

In fact, if you did use a more current version (9.1 or later), you could use [Foreign Data Wrappers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html) (FDW).  Someone has even posted [source code for a TDS FDW](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#tds_fdw), which should work for older SQL Server.

If you're somehow stuck with PostgreSQL 8.3, user [DBI-Link](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/dbi-link) as Craig Suggests.